# Reiterate over nested ifelse statements in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, dplyr, rowwise

Here is a tibble I have.

```
data_current <- structure(list(ID = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005), Posttest.Scenario.1.Pair = c(4, 
    1, 4, 4, 4), Posttest.Scenario.2.Pair = c(5, 4, 5, 3, 5), Posttest.Scenario.3.Pair = c(2, 
    3, 3, 5, 2), Posttest.Scenario.4.Pair = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 3), Posttest.Scenario.5.Pair = c(3, 
    5, 2, 2, 1), Posttest.Pair.1.Scenario = c("Driveway Drunk", "Driveway Drunk", 
    "Driveway Drunk", "Locked Out", "Driveway Drunk"), Posttest.Pair.2.Scenario = c("Parking Lot Duo", 
    "Parking Lot Duo", "Domestic Disturbance", "Domestic Disturbance", 
    "Domestic Disturbance"), Posttest.Pair.3.Scenario = c("Baby on Bridge", 
    "Down and Out", "Down and Out", "Baby on Bridge", "Down and Out"
    ), Posttest.Pair.4.Scenario = c("Homeless at Business", "Biker Billy", 
    "Biker Billy", "Homeless at Business", "Biker Billy"), Posttest.Pair.5.Scenario = c("NASA EDP", 
    "Misery Mountain", "Misery Mountain", "NASA EDP", "Misery Mountain"
    )), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 
        4L, 5L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("rowwise_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Pardon the scenario names; they are names of police training scenarios. There are five "pairs" of scenarios. Within each pair, each participant randomly gets one scenario at pretest (already completed) and the other at posttest.

The columns named "Posttest.Scenario.x.Pair" contain the pair name (i.e., 3) in that ordinal position of presentation. For example, if Posttest.Scenario.1.Pair = 4, that means that the first posttest scenario will be the assigned scenario from pair #4.

The columns named "Posttest.Pair.x.Scenario" contain the names of the posttest scenarios allocated for each of the 5 pairs.

I am trying to create the additional five columns to the right ("Posttest.Scenario.x"). These should contain the names (rather than the pair identifier) of scenarios by their order of presentation:

```
    data_desired <- structure(list(ID = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005), Posttest.Scenario.1.Pair = c(4, 
1, 4, 4, 4), Posttest.Scenario.2.Pair = c(5, 4, 5, 3, 5), Posttest.Scenario.3.Pair = c(2, 
3, 3, 5, 2), Posttest.Scenario.4.Pair = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 3), Posttest.Scenario.5.Pair = c(3, 
5, 2, 2, 1), Posttest.Pair.1.Scenario = c("Driveway Drunk", "Driveway Drunk", 
"Driveway Drunk", "Locked Out", "Driveway Drunk"), Posttest.Pair.2.Scenario = c("Parking Lot Duo", 
"Parking Lot Duo", "Domestic Disturbance", "Domestic Disturbance", 
"Domestic Disturbance"), Posttest.Pair.3.Scenario = c("Baby on Bridge", 
"Down and Out", "Down and Out", "Baby on Bridge", "Down and Out"
), Posttest.Pair.4.Scenario = c("Homeless at Business", "Biker Billy", 
"Biker Billy", "Homeless at Business", "Biker Billy"), Posttest.Pair.5.Scenario = c("NASA EDP", 
"Misery Mountain", "Misery Mountain", "NASA EDP", "Misery Mountain"
), Posttest.Scenario.1 = c("Homeless at Business", "Driveway Drunk", 
"Biker Billy", "Homeless at Business", "Biker Billy"), Posttest.Scenario.2 = c("NASA EDP", 
"Biker Billy", "Misery Mountain", "Baby on Bridge", "Misery Mountain"
), Posttest.Scenario.3 = c("Parking Lot Duo", "Down and Out", 
"Down and Out", "NASA EDP", "Domestic Disturbance"), Posttest.Scenario.4 = c("Driveway Drunk", 
"Parking Lot Duo", "Driveway Drunk", "Locked Out", "Down and Out"
), Posttest.Scenario.5 = c("Baby on Bridge", "Misery Mountain", 
"Domestic Disturbance", "Domestic Disturbance", "Driveway Drunk"
)), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("rowwise_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is what I wrote, which gets the job done:

```
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(`Posttest Scenario 1` = ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.1.Pair == 1, Posttest.Pair.1.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.1.Pair == 2, Posttest.Pair.2.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.1.Pair == 3, Posttest.Pair.3.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.1.Pair == 4, Posttest.Pair.4.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.1.Pair == 5, Posttest.Pair.5.Scenario,"NA"))))),
         `Posttest Scenario 2` = ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.2.Pair == 1, Posttest.Pair.1.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.2.Pair == 2, Posttest.Pair.2.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.2.Pair == 3, Posttest.Pair.3.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.2.Pair == 4, Posttest.Pair.4.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.2.Pair == 5, Posttest.Pair.5.Scenario,"NA"))))),
         `Posttest Scenario 3` = ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.3.Pair == 1, Posttest.Pair.1.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.3.Pair == 2, Posttest.Pair.2.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.3.Pair == 3, Posttest.Pair.3.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.3.Pair == 4, Posttest.Pair.4.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.3.Pair == 5, Posttest.Pair.5.Scenario,"NA"))))),
         `Posttest Scenario 4` = ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.4.Pair == 1, Posttest.Pair.1.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.4.Pair == 2, Posttest.Pair.2.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.4.Pair == 3, Posttest.Pair.3.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.4.Pair == 4, Posttest.Pair.4.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.4.Pair == 5, Posttest.Pair.5.Scenario,"NA"))))),
         `Posttest Scenario 5` = ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.5.Pair == 1, Posttest.Pair.1.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.5.Pair == 2, Posttest.Pair.2.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.5.Pair == 3, Posttest.Pair.3.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.5.Pair == 4, Posttest.Pair.4.Scenario,
                                 ifelse(Posttest.Scenario.5.Pair == 5, Posttest.Pair.5.Scenario,"NA"))))))
```

But I know that's horrible and couple be vastly improved. I just don't know how to do it. Is it a loop that uses a function? Can you please help?

Comment: Can you post the data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(df))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use case_when and loop through the columns `Posttest.Scenario.1.Pair`through `Posttest.Scenario.5.Pair`

```
library(dplyr)

new_data <- data_current %>% mutate(across(Posttest.Scenario.1.Pair:Posttest.Scenario.5.Pair, ~ case_when(
          .x==1 ~ Posttest.Pair.1.Scenario,
          .x==2 ~ Posttest.Pair.2.Scenario,
          .x==3 ~ Posttest.Pair.3.Scenario,
          .x==4 ~ Posttest.Pair.4.Scenario,
          .x==5 ~ Posttest.Pair.5.Scenario,
          TRUE ~ NA_character_), .names = "{paste0('Posttest.Scenario.', 1:5)}"))

identical(new_data, data_desired)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Ok - but I think this changes the "Postest.Scenario.x.Pair" columns from a number to a name. I would like to retain the "Postest.Scenario.x.Pair" columns with the numbers, and create an extra 5 columns ("Posttest.Scenario.x") with the scenario names.

Comment: added a `.names` argument now. Should work as requested.

Comment: there was a typo. Corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

A generalized solution, in case you not only have 5 but beyond:

```
d <- data_current %>%
  left_join(pivot_longer(.,-ID, names_to = '.value', names_pattern =  '(\\w+)$')%>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    transmute(value = Scenario[Pair], 
              name = paste0('Posttest.Scenario.', seq(n()))) %>%
    pivot_wider()
  )
```

We could test for equality:

```
all.equal(d, data_desired)
[1] TRUE
```